# What is the limit of $ \sqrt[n]{ a^ n + b^ n}$ when $n \to \infty$ for $a,b ≥ 0$

Tags: analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I want to caclulate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {\sqrt[n]{ a^ n  + b^ n  } }$$ for a,b ≥ 0

I wanted to isolate $\sqrt[n]{a^n}$ but I really don't know how to show that the limit is 1.

I know that $\sqrt[n]a \rightarrow 1$ ,so I thought that I seperate the function to $\sqrt[n]{a^n}$ and $\sqrt[n]{b^n}$ and show that they are equally going to the same limit.
So that $\sqrt{a^n}$ and $\sqrt{b^n} = \lim{\sqrt[n]{ a^{ n } + b^{ n } } }$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. The result depends on $a$ and $b$. In general, the limit is $\max(a,b)$.

Comment: I hope the edit did not change the intent of the question. Please check it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You have to enclose MathJax commands in `$` signs before they will be effective.  Also, you have to write \ before functions like sqrt.  `$\sqrt[n]{a^n + b^n}$` is typeset as $\sqrt[n]{a^n + b^n}$  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: [Several very similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/130497), although unless I'm overlooking something, your limit is much simpler --- factor $a^n + b^n$ as $a^n(1 + (b/a)^n)$ or as $b^n((a/b)^n + 1),$ depending on whether $a > b$ or $b > a.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $\max(a,b)$. Assume WLOG that $a> b$. Then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {\sqrt[n]{ a^ n  + b^ n  } }=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a{\sqrt[n]{ 1  + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n  } }=a$$

since

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[n]{ 1  + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n  } }=1$$

On the other hand, if $a=b$ then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {\sqrt[n]{ a^ n  + b^ n  } }=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {\sqrt[n]{2a^n} }=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2^{1/n}a=a$$

Comment: How would a beginner prove $\lim \sqrt[n]{1 +r^n} =1$ if $0 < r < 1$? (Or for that matter that $\lim\sqrt[n]{1 + r^n} = r$ if $r > 1$).  You can't say as $n\to\infty$ that $1+r^n\to 0$ because you can't separate the limits.  What's the beginner to do?

Comment: @fleablood They could observe that $1 < 1+r^n <2$.

Comment: What did you do in the first line ? I do not understand how sqrt a+b is a * sqrt 1+(b/a)^n. Where is then "n" from a^n?

Comment: ${\sqrt[n]{ a^ n  + b^ n  } }=(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}=\left(a^n\left(1+\frac{b^n}{a^n}\right)\right)^{1/n}=\left(a^n\left(1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n\right)\right)^{1/n}$